# form load but the process does not stop

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I'm having a problem viewing my records from an arraylist in JSP page. Every time I load my JSP page automatically by javascript onload event, data is displayed but the process does not stop.

`Categoria` class:

```
package proyecto.modelo;

public class Categoria {

    private int idcategoria;

    public int getIdcategoria() {
        return idcategoria;
    }

    public void setIdcategoria(int idcategoria) {       
        this.idcategoria = idcategoria;
    }
}
```

`BaseDAO` class:

```
package proyecto.dao;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class BaseDAO {

    protected void cerrarConexion(Connection con) throws RuntimeException {
        try {
            if (con != null && !con.isClosed()) {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.err.println("Error: cerrarConexion: " + se);
        }
    }

    protected void cerrarResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws RuntimeException {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.err.println("Error: cerrarResultSet: " + se);
        }
    }

    protected void cerrarStatement(PreparedStatement stmt)
            throws RuntimeException {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.err.println("Error: cerrarStatement: " + se);
        }
    }

    protected void cerrarCallable(CallableStatement callstmt)
            throws RuntimeException {
        try {
            if (callstmt != null) {
                callstmt.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.err.println("Error: cerrarCallable: " + se);
        }
    }
}
```

`CategoriaDAO` class:

```
package proyecto.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import proyecto.excepcion.DAOExcepcion;
import proyecto.modelo.Categoria;
import proyecto.util.ConexionBD;

public class CategoriaDAO extends BaseDAO {

    public Collection<Categoria> listarIdCat() throws DAOExcepcion{

        Collection<Categoria> = new ArrayList<Categoria>();
        String query = "SELECT id_categoria from categoria ";
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            con=ConexionBD.obtenerConexionDirecta();
            stmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs=stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) {
                Categoria vo=new Categoria();
                vo.setIdcategoria(rs.getInt("id_categoria"));
                c.add(vo);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new DAOExcepcion(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            this.cerrarStatement(stmt);
            this.cerrarResultSet(rs);
            this.cerrarConexion(con);
        }

        return c;
    }

}
```

`CategoriaNegocio` class:

```
package proyecto.negocio;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import proyecto.dao.CategoriaDAO;
import proyecto.excepcion.DAOExcepcion;
import proyecto.modelo.Categoria;

public class CategoriaNegocio {

    public Collection<Categoria> listarIdCat() throws DAOExcepcion {
        CategoriaDAO dao = new CategoriaDAO();
        Collection<Categoria> lista = dao.listarIdCat();
        return lista;
    }

}
```

Servlets `doPost()` method:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    CategoriaNegocio negocio = new CategoriaNegocio();

    try {
        Collection<Categoria> lista = negocio.listarIdCat();
        request.setAttribute("IDCATEGORIA", lista);
    } catch (DAOExcepcion e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("listar_idcat.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

JSP:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"   %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                document.formulario.submit()
            };
            document.close();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="ListarIdCatServlet" method="post" name="formulario"></form>
        <table>
            <c:forEach items="${IDCATEGORIA}" var="c">
                <tr>
                    <td>${c.idcategoria}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dude, format your question properly! And remove all of the unnecessary code so that we're only trying to understand the bit that's actually relevant to your problem

Comment: Can you tell me why you are trying to submit your form on page load?

Comment: what I want is for the page to load automatically without button

Comment: Use the quote button to format quotes and use the code button to format code. Do not use both quote and code button to format code. Even more, in your entire question, you do not have any quotes, so you should not have used the quote button in the whole question at all.

Comment: I fixed the insane formatting. I noticed that you've even removed all `>` characters, making the code syntactically invalid. You should not do that. Just select code and press code button. That's all. Really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to invoke a servlet on a GET request. You're approaching this the wrong way. You should not be submitting a POST form on load of the page. You should be performing the job in the `doGet()` method of the servlet and be invoking it directly.

You need to make the following changes:

1. Change URL pattern of servlet to `/listar_idcat`.
2. Rename `doPost` method of servlet to `doGet`.
3. Move `listar_idcat.jsp` file into `/WEB-INF` folder (this prevents direct access by endusers).
4. Change `getRequestDispatcher("listar_idcat.jsp");` call in servlet to `getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/listar_idcat.jsp");`.
5. Remove the whole `<script>` from JSP.
6. Remove the whole `<form>` from JSP.

Now, open the JSP by `http://localhost:8080/context/listar_idcat` instead (yes, without the `.jsp` extension! it'll invoke the servlet's `doGet()` directly).

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - Hello World #2.

Comment: Thank you very much friend recently I'm starting in the world of web java if you could help me be as good as you know of some manuals friend and thanks.

Comment: Hello BalusC if you could give me an idea for listarme after the combobox insert the data

Comment: If you have a new and independent question, you should press `Ask Question` button. You should not use `Add Comment` button on a completely different question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984371/how-to-insert-a-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-selecting-it-for-a-combobox